# Compiling error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [5]’ and ‘double (*)(double, double, double, double, double)’ to binary ‘operator+’

Tags: c++, string, function

I'm attempting to make a print function where I combine a few pieces of text and a numerical value obtained from a function. I receive the error when compiling:

#### Error Message

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [5]’ and ‘double (*)(double, double, double, double, double)’ to binary ‘operator+’
  wrtResult = ("s = " + sortValues + " kJ/(kg.K)");
```

#### Source Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void eqOut(double sortValues(double tempC,double xo,double yo,double xone,double yone))
{
    string wrtResult; 
    wrtResult = ("s = " + sortValues + " kJ/(kg.K)"); // This is the line in question
    cout << wrtResult;
}

int main()
{
    double tempC;
    double xo, xone, yo, yone;

    cout << "Enter a temp in C : ";
    cin >> tempC;


    if ((tempC < 150) || (tempC > 500))

    {
        cout << "Enter a value between 150 and 500 next time!" << endl;
    }

    else
    {

        double sortValues(double tempC,double xo,double yo,double xone,double yone);
        {

            double temp150 = 150, temp200 = 200,
                   temp250 = 250, temp300 = 300,
                   temp400 = 400, temp500 = 500;

            double ent150 = 7.2810, ent200 = 7.5081,
                   ent250= 7.7100, ent300 = 7.8941,
                   ent400 = 8.2236, ent500 = 8.5153;

            double x;


            if (tempC == 150)
            {
                cout << "7.2810 kJ/(kg.K)";
            }

            if (tempC > 150 && tempC < 200)
            {
                x = tempC;
                xo = ent150; 
                xone = ent200;
                yo = temp150;
                yone = temp200;
                return (yone+(yone-yo)*((x-xo)/(xone-xo)));
            }

            if (tempC > 200 && tempC < 250)
            {
                x = tempC;
                xo = ent200;
                xone = ent250;
                yo = temp200;
                yone = temp250;
                return (yone+(yone-yo)*((x-xo)/(xone-xo)));
            }

            if ((tempC > 250) && (tempC < 300))
            {
                x = tempC;
                xo = ent250;
                xone = ent300;
                yo = temp250;
                yone = temp300;
                return (yone+(yone-yo)*((x-xo)/(xone-xo)));
            }

            if ((tempC > 300) && (tempC < 400))
            {
                x = tempC;
                xo = ent300;
                xone = ent400;
                yo = temp300;
                yone = temp400;
                return (yone+(yone-yo)*((x-xo)/(xone-xo)));
            }
            if ((tempC > 400) && (tempC < 500))
            {
                x = tempC;
                xo = ent400;
                xone = ent500;
                yo = temp400;
                yone = temp500;
                return (yone+(yone-yo)*((x-xo)/(xone-xo)));
            }
        }
    }

    eqOut;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know where to start with this

Comment: You need to [get a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: That bad huh? Yikes. We were just introduced functions yesterday so I'm sure that I'm misunderstanding them entirely. Maybe I should go back to the drawing board here and remove this statement all together.

Comment: @Buttons _"That bad huh?"_ Sorry to say that, but: Yes! It's that bad ...

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for that >_< Exceptionally useful.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
wrtResult = ("s = " + sortValues + " kJ/(kg.K)");
```

`sortValues` is a function pointer. Its name, when not followed by parentheses, refers to the function pointer value; it doesn't call the function.

You probably want something like:

```
wrtResult = ("s = " + sortValues(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0) + " kJ/(kg.K)");
```

though obviously with more sensible arguments. (I say "something like", but not too much like that, since you can't add a string literal and a `double.. If you want to append values to strings, use`std::string` rather than C-style strings; you can do it with C-style strings, but you have to manage the memory yourself.)

That explains the error message. In the body of `main`, you've got some serious problems.

It looks like you're trying to define a function inside another function definition:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    double sortValues(...);
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But in a function definition, you can't have a semicolon after the parameter list. With the semicolon, you have a function *declaration* (for a function that needs to be *defined* elsewhere) followed by an unrelated compound statement delimited by `{` and `}`.

You need to move the definition of your `sortValues` function to the top level, outside the definition of `main`.

Comment: Even then that's still broken, since you can't add a C-style string and a `double`.

Comment: As @T.C. said, you should probably use `std::to_string`.

Comment: So I can do else and just call the function that is defined elsewhere? In regard to the C-style string 'double' I presume you are referring to the + functionpointer + ?

Comment: @Buttons _"So I can do else and just call the function that is defined elsewhere?"_ That's the usual concept, yes. Even if you would fully define your function at that place, you would need to call it afterwards.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the wisdom stackcrew! I'll rearrange, simplify and give it another go.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...
double sortValues(double tempC,double xo,double yo,double xone,double yone);
                                                                        // ^ Semicolon is wrong!
{
// ...
```

This looks very wrong! Function declaration within a function body, and unrelated definition code following.